# msg: "{{ item[0] | select ('match','^(feature|dev)) }}" returning all the directories instead of directories prefixing feature or dev

Tags: ansible

```yaml
- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item[0] | select ('match','^(feature|dev)) }}"
  loop: "{{ result.files }}"
  loop_control: 
    extended: yes 
    label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

The above code lists all the directories in the given path "/tmp".
How can I list or filter directories starting with "feature|dev" (for example, directories like dev032623, dev011519, dev, devant, feature032623, feature011519, feature_ron, featureant).

I tried the following "msg" string:

```yaml
"{{ item[0] | select ('match','^(feature|dev)) }}"
```

but it is returning all the directories in the list.

Placing playbook for your reference

```yaml
- name: List old directories 
  find: 
    paths: /tmp
    age: 30d 
    file_type: directory
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item[0] | select ('match','^(feature|dev)) }}"
  loop: "{{ result.files }}"
  loop_control: 
    extended: yes 
    label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

The above code listing all the directories in the given path /tmp instead of matching with feature/dev

Answer (score 1):

Given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── bar
├── dev01
├── dev02
├── feature01
├── feature02
└── foo

6 directories, 0 files
```

Find the directories and iterate the *result*

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
        file_type: directory
      register: result

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: /tmp/test/feature01
  msg: /tmp/test/dev01
  msg: /tmp/test/bar
  msg: /tmp/test/foo
  msg: /tmp/test/dev02
  msg: /tmp/test/feature02
```

Map the attribute *paths* and get the *basename*. Then *select* the pattern. Declare the variable

```yaml
  feature_dev: "{{ result.files|
                   map(attribute='path')|
                   map('basename')|
                   select('match', 'feature|dev') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  feature_dev:
  - feature01
  - dev01
  - dev02
  - feature02
```

Put the condition into the loop if you want to iterate the selected paths

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
      when: item.path|basename is match('feature|dev')
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: /tmp/test/feature01
  msg: /tmp/test/dev01
  msg: /tmp/test/dev02
  msg: /tmp/test/feature02
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    feature_dev: "{{ result.files|
                     map(attribute='path')|
                     map('basename')|
                     select('match', 'feature|dev') }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
        file_type: directory
      register: result

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
      when: item.path|basename is match('feature|dev')

    - debug:
        var: feature_dev
```

---

- Use the filter [*community.general.dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) and create the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
  dir_file: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|
                zip(result.files|map(attribute='path')|map('dirname'))|
                zip(result.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename'))|
                map('flatten')|
                map('zip', ['path', 'dirname', 'filename'])|
                map('map', 'reverse')|
                map('community.general.dict')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dir_file:
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: feature01, path: /tmp/test/feature01}
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: dev01, path: /tmp/test/dev01}
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: bar, path: /tmp/test/bar}
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: foo, path: /tmp/test/foo}
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: dev02, path: /tmp/test/dev02}
    - {dirname: /tmp/test, filename: feature02, path: /tmp/test/feature02}
```

*map* the *path* where the *filname* *match* the pattern

```yaml
  feature_dev_path: "{{ dir_file|
                        selectattr('filename', 'match', 'feature|dev')|
                        map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  feature_dev_path:
  - /tmp/test/feature01
  - /tmp/test/dev01
  - /tmp/test/dev02
  - /tmp/test/feature02
```

---

- You can also use the filter [*'community.general.dict_kv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries). The declarations below give the same result

```yaml
  path: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"
  dirs: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|map('dirname')|
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'dirname') }}"
  base: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'filename') }}"
  dir_file: "{{ path|zip(dirs)|zip(base)|
                map('flatten')|
                map('combine') }}"
```

---

- Jinja also provides a simple option how to create the list of the dictionaries. The declarations below also give the same result

```yaml
  dir_file_str: |
    [{% for i in result.files|map(attribute='path')|list %}
    {dirname: {{ i|dirname }}, filename: {{ i|basename }}, path: {{ i }}},
    {% endfor %}]
  dir_file: "{{ dir_file_str|from_yaml }}"
```